# Find Marker by Tag Google Maps API (Android)

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How/Where could I get a reference of all marker objects current on the map, in order to check something like this:

```
if (Markers.getTag().equals("something"))
```

By reading the documentation on Marker it said "This is easier than storing a separate Map", so I don't want to use HashMap unless someone say I absolutely have to.

Thanks, the following is a pseudo-pseudo code

// The uid is the Marker's tag

// 1) **Someway to Check if the tag exists for the current profile**

// 2) **If it exists, then just move the marker, just set a new position of this marker.**

// 3) If it doesn't, then create a new marker, add a marker.

// 4) Set profile uid as the Marker's Tag, via .setTag()

// 5) Animate move camera to the latlng position

3-5 is okay, just 1-2

```
// 3) Create a new marker
                            // Marker to show on the map
                            Marker friendMarker;

                            // Add a marker when the image is loaded
                            friendMarker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                            .position(friendLatLng)
                                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap))
                                            .title(friendProfile.getName()));

                            // Set the tag on this friend marker, so we can retrieve or update it later
                            friendMarker.setTag(friendProfile.getUid());

                            // 5) Animate the camera to that location
                            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(friendLatLng).zoom(15).build();
                            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a List of Marker

```
List<Marker> markers = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then add your marker in your markers list

```
// Marker to show on the map
Marker friendMarker;

// Add a marker when the image is loaded
friendMarker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
               .position(friendLatLng)                     
               .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap))
               .title(friendProfile.getName()));

//Add now the marker in markers list
markers.add(friendMarker);
```

Then to access all markers

```
for (Marker marker : markers) {
     if (marker.getTag().equals("something")) { //if a marker has desired tag
         //Do something in the way. Hmmmm. Yeah
     }
}
```

Comment: Thx, I was hoping there are some way I missed with the setTag() and getTag(). If List and Map is the only way, then ok. I 've already implemented a hashmap with setTag() keys , and list is not much different.